# How to set encrypt_password property when connecting to Sybase using Hibernate and JTDS

Tags: java, spring-boot, sybase, jtds

I am trying to connect Sybase which has set encrypt_password property to true. The JTDS version I am using is newest version I can find in Maven: 1.3.1 released in 2013 Jun.

I am getting error:ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Adaptive Server requires encryption of the login password on the network

Here is the DB Config code:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(dbConn.getDriverClassName());
    dataSource.setUrl(dbConn.getUrl());
    dataSource.setUsername(dbConn.getUsername());
    dataSource.setPassword(dbConn.getPassword());

 // setting driver properties
    Properties props = new Properties();
    for(String propPair: dbConn.getDriverProperties().split(",")) {
         String[] prop = propPair.split("=");
        props.setProperty(prop[0], prop[1]);
    }

    dataSource.setConnectionProperties(props);


    return dataSource;
}
```

and in application.yml file:

```
connection:
    driverProperties: "ENCRYPT_PASSWORD=true"
```

However this still does not work and I am getting this error:
ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Adaptive Server requires encryption of the login password on the network

I have made some search but the answer people left seems frustrating:
https://sourceforge.net/p/jtds/discussion/104389/thread/90e1bb7f/

Is there anyway I can do this property manually? Thanks in advance for reading this question and potentially if you have the answer.

Comment: BTW my project originally use JConn4, but this driver can not be recognized by Hibernate for some reason after we upgrading from Java 8 to Java 11. Though not related to above question technically speaking.

Comment: Maybe this will help although its for DBVisualiser it helps with the setup of JTDS as it doesn't have the relevant driver for password encryption: https://support.dbvis.com/support/solutions/articles/1000231934-sybase-ase-how-to-enable-password-encryption